# How do I export a Gridview Control to Excel in DotNetNuke?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

Is there an alternative to using this since using a `<form runat="server">` will cause a 500 error.

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

***EDITED***

With the assistance from @HansDerks I ended up using the following(a jazzed up version of the solution provided.):

```
protected void Export_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.DataSource = MySqlDataSource;
        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gridView.DataBind();
        gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#003c74");
        gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#ffffff");
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[i];

            //Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

            //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
            }
        }
        gridView.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        htmlWriter.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Write(writer.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

I hope you guys will find it useful. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Is there an alternative to using "what"?

Comment: @ChrisHammond `public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)`

I am currently looking at using telerik controls. I am having trouble though since I cannot compile without the QuickStart.dll

Comment: @ChrisHammond without telerik is there another way? I cannot use the `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` in my custom module because it relies on the use of a `<form runat="server">` tag. Currently I am researching a telerik option. If there is any other way please let me know? If you have a sample module out there so I can reference please also let me know. I am using DNN 6.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the datasource you can try this (replace datatable with relevant datasource)

```
private void DataTableToExcel(DataTable dataTable)
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
    GridView gridView = new GridView();
    gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    gridView.DataBind();
    gridView.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    htmlWriter.Close();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Write(writer.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully...I jazzed it up a bit, but i am not sure I followed my order of operations correctly, I will place my final draft in my original post under ***Edited***

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DNN grid control, which is based on a Telerik control, you can export the visible contents of the grid with:

```
protected void OnExportCSVClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdMemberTypes.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV();
}
```

This applies to DNN 7.0 though.

Unfortunately, if you have paging turned on, it only outputs the data from the visible rows.

Comment: [DNN UX Guide](http://uxguide.dotnetnuke.com/UIPatterns/dnnGrid.aspx), 
[Telerik RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx)