# Export DataTable to Excel File not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I checked many solutions but neither of them working for me. I tried NaveenBhat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192053/1707848)
and Akhter's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746924/1707848) as well. Code runs well and there is not any error but file save popup is not appearing. I tried 2 browsers(i.e. Chrome and Firefox) and confirmed that localHost current port is allowed popups. Stuck now.

**Is there anything missing in those 2 answers? OR**

**What should i try to Export excel from DataTable in C#?**

Comment: Any chance that you post your code here?

Comment: two common libraries to write to excel using C#.NET are microsoft.office.interop.excel or openXML

Comment: I would try completely disabling the popup blocker.

Comment: @L_7337 i tried that but there is no popup

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is Turning Down your Security Settings and making sure there is nothing in Internet Options to prevent downloads.  Those solutions should just write to your Response stream and pull up on your browser.

Comment: Maybe you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766914/how-do-i-export-a-gridview-control-to-excel-in-dotnetnuke/18780825#18780825